# Find all numeric literals in Java code

Tags: java, eclipse

I am supporting external code and I want to extract all constants and magic numbers from the code. Is there any fast way of doing it in Eclipse?

Comment: grep for `\d+` (you can even do that from Eclipses search dialog). It might show a few false positives, but that's probably the fastest you can do.

Comment: Are you looking for a batch "Extract Constant..." refactoring?

Comment: @JoachimSauer It did the trick, thank you!

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if is fits you.

Comment: @user1598390 Unfortunately it is comment that solved OP problem, but comments can't be accepted as answer.

Comment: @Andreas_D Yes, that would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/), an code static analysys tool, that can work as an Eclipse plug-in. It will flag  magic numers so you don't have to look for them yourself.

Comment: There is a pmd plugin for eclipse so you can see the "results" in your source code (markers)

Comment: I did not know what I was looking for until you told me. This will prove very useful. Thank you.

Comment: The tool is behaving greatly but it doesn't find magic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Externalize Wizard](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-wizard-externalize-strings.htm) from time to time. That will help you with Strings mostly. Just select the compilation unit (the java file) and in the Source menu, select Externalize.

For numbers I haven't found nor a wizard nor a plugin for doing this, you will have to select "Extract Constant" in the refactoring submenu of the contextual menu (right-click).